# Is there a way to delete the children table in multiple polymorphic relationship rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

For example, I have three models right now. A credential, a record and a item.

```
class Credential < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :records, dependent: :destroy
end

class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :syncable, polymorphic: true
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :records, as: :syncable, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Let's say, in the credential controller, there is a destroy method:

```
def destroy
  @credential.destroy
end
```

This can only delete the data in credential and record table but not the item table. Is there a way to delete data in item table when I delete data in credential table and record table?

Comment: This should destroy the `item` instance. In your association, you should have `has_one :record, as: ...` not `records`